# Unable to get stored struct data from rinkby but works in ganache-cli

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I am working on a school project where I am writing struct data and trying to read back.
When I am using ganache-cli - it works correct. When I am trying to get data using rinkeby testnet (infera), the data recieved is the same initialized data. Both my solidity and python codes are attached. I have referred https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=6907s for writing the code.

--solidity code----

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
contract IoTDataStorage {
    struct IoT {
        string date;         
        uint data;  
        bool status;       
    }
 
mapping (address => IoT) public iotDevice;

function set(string memory _date, uint _data, bool _status) public returns(bool) {
        iotDevice[msg.sender].date = _date;
        iotDevice[msg.sender].data = _data;
        iotDevice[msg.sender].status = _status;
        return true;
    }

    function get() public view returns(IoT memory) {
        return iotDevice[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

---python code---

```
import json

from web3 import Web3


# from solcx import compile_standard
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

with open("./IoTDataStorage.sol","r") as file:
    iot_storage_file = file.read()

install_solc("0.8.0")
# Solidity source code
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"IoTDataStorage.sol": {"content": iot_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.8.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["IoTDataStorage.sol"]["IoTDataStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["IoTDataStorage.sol"]["IoTDataStorage"]["abi"]



# For connecting to ganache
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))
chain_id = 1337
my_address = "0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1"
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")

# Create the contract in Python
IoTDataStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
# Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
# Submit the transaction that deploys the contract
transaction = IoTDataStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
# Sign the transaction
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
print("Deploying Contract!")
# Send it!
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
# Wait for the transaction to be mined, and get the transaction receipt
print("Waiting for transaction to finish...")
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
print(f"Done! Contract deployed to {tx_receipt.contractAddress}")


# Working with deployed Contracts
iot_storage = w3.eth.contract(address=tx_receipt.contractAddress, abi=abi)
print(f"Initial Stored Value {iot_storage.functions.get().call()}")
greeting_transaction = iot_storage.functions.set("15-02-2022",120,True).buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce + 1,
    }
)
signed_greeting_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    greeting_transaction, private_key=private_key
)
tx_greeting_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_greeting_txn.rawTransaction)
print("Updating stored Value...")
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_greeting_hash)


print(f"Current Stored Value {iot_storage.functions.get().call()}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the data recieved is the same initialized data"? Can you verify if the transaction that call `set` had succeeded? On real blockchains the transactions usually take some time to be mined, if you query a contract before it is mined you won't see any change.

Comment: Please see my results.Deploying Contract!
Waiting for transaction to finish...
Done! Contract deployed to 0x75d6441993d67213a1DfDabFcdc0235316D7A347
Initial Stored Value ('', 0, False)
Updating stored Value...
Current Stored Value ('', 0, False)...   The results are the same as the initial value which is set by the constructor. I have set additional wait time as well, was not helping.

Comment: Looking at the [transaction changes](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xcd5a6a634af500c1f824e157f1bdd2226117f60205357aee77368a64903db478#statechange) the contract storage was updated correctly. My guess is that web3.py may require to specify `from` in the [call](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.call) something like `iot_storage.functions.get().call("from": my_address)`. I'd try to avoid using `msg.sender` in a view function for that problem, and instead explicitly require an address parameter.

Comment: Thanks Ismael, I have modified like this  function get(address iotData_address) public view returns(IoT memory) {
        return iotDevice[iotData_address];
    }. It works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ismael. solution is as below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
contract IoTDataStorage {
    struct IoT {
        string date;         
        uint data;  
        bool status;       
    }
 
mapping (address => IoT) public iotDevice;

function set(string memory _date, uint _data, bool _status) public returns(bool) {
        iotDevice[msg.sender].date = _date;
        iotDevice[msg.sender].data = _data;
        iotDevice[msg.sender].status = _status;
        return true;
    }

    function get(address iotData_address) public view returns(IoT memory) {
        return iotDevice[iotData_address];
    }
}
```

--python--

```
import json

from web3 import Web3


# from solcx import compile_standard
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time

load_dotenv()

with open("./IoTDataStorage.sol","r") as file:
    iot_storage_file = file.read()

install_solc("0.8.0")
# Solidity source code
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"IoTDataStorage.sol": {"content": iot_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.8.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["IoTDataStorage.sol"]["IoTDataStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["IoTDataStorage.sol"]["IoTDataStorage"]["abi"]



# For connecting to ganache
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/007a409acfd0492a9334245028b6d257"))
chain_id = 4
my_address = "0x386F09c04470d44f2fc26F699A041B00A4fCa5Cf"
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")

# Create the contract in Python
IoTDataStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
# Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
# Submit the transaction that deploys the contract
transaction = IoTDataStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
# Sign the transaction
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
print("Deploying Contract!")
# Send it!
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
# Wait for the transaction to be mined, and get the transaction receipt
print("Waiting for transaction to finish...")
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
print(f"Done! Contract deployed to {tx_receipt.contractAddress}")


# Working with deployed Contracts
iot_storage = w3.eth.contract(address=tx_receipt.contractAddress, abi=abi)
print(f"Initial Stored Value {iot_storage.functions.get(my_address).call(block_identifier='latest')}")
greeting_transaction = iot_storage.functions.set("15-02-2022",120,True).buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce + 1,
    }
)
signed_greeting_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    greeting_transaction, private_key=private_key
)
tx_greeting_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_greeting_txn.rawTransaction)
print("Updating stored Value...")
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_greeting_hash)

time.sleep(20)
print(f"Current Stored Value {iot_storage.functions.get(my_address).call(block_identifier='latest')}")
```